# Script piped into bash fails to expand globs during rm command

Tags: bash, io, pipe

I am writing a script with the intention of being able to download and run it from anywhere, like:

```sh
bash <(curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/path/to/script.sh)
```

The command above allows me to download the script, run interactive commands (e.g. `read`), and - for the most part - Just Works. I have run into an issue during the cleanup portion of my script, however, and haven't been able to discern a fix

During cleanup I need to remove several `.bkp` files created by the script's execution. To do so I run `rm -f **/*.bkp` inside the script. When a local copy of the script is run, this works great! When run via bash/curl, however, it removes nothing. I believe this has something to do with a failure to expand the glob as a result of the way I've connected the I/O of bash and curl, but have been unable to find a way to get everything to play nice

## How can I meet all of the following requirements?

- Download and run a script from a remote resource
- Ensure that the user's keyboard input is connected for use in e.g. `read` calls within the script
- Correctly expand the glob passed to `rm`
- *Bonus points:* colorize input with e.g. `echo -e "\x1b[31mSome error text here\x1b[0m"` (also not working, suspected to be related to the same bash/curl I/O issues)

Comment: For `**` to work you need version 4+ with the globstar option enabled (it's off by default). This applies no matter where the script comes from (ps: please ensure you do not delete the user's existing `.bkp` files with this very aggressive pattern)

Comment: @thatotherguy This would be run from the context of a directory that _must_ be created by the script before it will try to do anything else, so any matches should be new files. That said: if you're right about this being the root of my problem it'll probably be a better option to be verbose/explicit than use that glob

Comment: @thatotherguy Why would that option be set if he runs a local copy of the script instead of running it using process substitution?

Comment: @Barmar locally I think I might have been running zsh instead, which - if true - could probably explain the difference I'd seen when running the script there

Comment: I don't know. As mentioned, this should apply regardless. OP, what's the command you use to run the script locally, and is that on the same machine?

Comment: If you execute the script using `bash scriptname` it doesn't matter what shell you're running interactively.

Comment: I'd just been executing via `path/to/script.sh` locally - and yes, same machine. Also: confirmed that laptop runs zsh by default. Biggest problem here might be my inattentiveness, SMH

Comment: If you are running the script directly (i.e., as `./script.sh` instead of something like `bash script.sh`), then the script likely uses a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)). Does your script have a shebang at the top of it? If you want your script to run as desired with bash, but it currently runs with zsh, you might need to turn on the globstar option, as pointed out by @thatotherguy.